# D3 can't set the style to appened objects

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, d3.js, styles

Usually, when you append an object in D3.js and you want to define an specific visualization (for example, an info box that appears at the top of another object) you set a style. In my case I'm trying this:

```
...
.on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
           graph.append("div")
                .attr("class","info-box")
                // info-box is defined with position: absolute
                .style("top", height - (yV * d))
                .style("left", (xV * i))
                .text("INFO")
}
...
```

So, in the case I make mouseover on one of the objects I defined with this code (let's say it's the second one in a series of vertical bars) there should appear a box with the following code:

```
<div class="info-box" style="top: 30; left: 10">
    INFO
</div>
```

The thing is, for some reason, when the code generate the box it doesn't set the style I've defined, in fact, the attribute "style" doesn't appear at all, which is quite annoying taking into consideration I want this box to appear at the top of the bar I'm hovering.

This happens to me in a code I'm working on in Spring MVC. To be more precise, I generate the javascript code from a custom tag that receives a couple of parameters and then it "renders" in a jsp that calls it with those parameters. I don't know if it has something to do or not, but I'm quite sure of two things:

1. There's no "collision" with other javascript files since d3 is the only .js I'm using with my code.
2. Exactly the same javascript code that is generated in the jsp works as expected in a common html page.

Some workaround for this? Some configuration made in Spring that prevents me to use styles nested in HTML? I would really apreciate an answer for this, since it's getting me crazy and I need to fix it ASAP.

Two last notes:

1. I've already tried using attr("style","top: " + (height - (yV * d)) + "; left" + (xV * i) + ";") and it DOESN'T works. :(
2. Using a class is NOT an option, since this depends heavily on the values of the object I'm hovering and I can't create a class for every possible scenario (I would slit my veins before doing that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the units, in this case 'px', in order to set these css properties.

```
.on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
       graph.append("div")
            .attr("class","info-box")
            // info-box is defined with position: absolute
            .style("top", (height - (yV * d)) + 'px')
            .style("left", (xV * i) + 'px')
            .text("INFO")
```

Comment: ... I don't know how my original code works for my html and not in jsp, but hey, in the end it was quite easy... sorry for asking stupid questions... but I've always set top and left properties without defining px.

Comment: You can do it w/o px in jQuery, which does some extra interpretation for you, but not with d3.